# How to develope an application with FlipBorad App style with HTML5

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app

Flipborad mobile app has a unique style, the screen will split in two half and the lower part will rotate on the upper part.

Can any one give some hint how to develop such a thing with HTML5 for Hybrid mobile apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be of use

http://engineering.flipboard.com/2015/02/mobile-web/

Flipboard is using react to render layout on canvas. That's why it's so quick and gives unlimited possibilities. However it's not very accessible unless you put a lot of effort into that.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot, but I will wait a while to see if somebody mentions a demo for this otherwise I mark your question as answer

Comment: Yeah. That's fine. I am not sure if they use it in this place. But it's quite big thing lately that they started using layout with "made up" elements based on canvas :)

Comment: Going once again to the question. From what I see all Flipboard apps use now react. In some places to improve performance of animations they use canvas. this blog post ( http://engineering.flipboard.com/2015/02/golden-gate/ ) suggests that all layout are done using webviews (to keep consistency between all apps) . Which means probably you can use html5 animations. If performance is to bad you can try to use canvas.